# Type Casting an Decoded Json Object to array, generate error while accessing it

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I decoded a json string and then Type casted it into any Array and tried to access it later. But it generate `Undefined Index` Error

Here is my sample code

```
$json = '{"1":"Active","0":"Inactive"}'; //Yes, it is a valid Json String
$decodedObject = json_decode($json);
$array = (array)$decodedObject;
echo $array['1']; // This generates undefinded Index 1 Error
```

Here is the display of the array and object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => Active
    [0] => Inactive
)

Array
(
    [1] => Active
    [0] => Inactive
)
```

Comment: Just do var_dump with $array and look what you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) instead of making it in two steps how about doing it like:

```
$decodedArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

it will directly give you the array instead of object

2.) make sure your json code is corret:

```
{"1":"Active","0":"Inactive"}
```

3.) your `var_dump` shows that `array{[1]=>....` so why refering it like `$array['1']` can it be even simpler `$array[1]`

Comment: wow, this fixed everything. I will accept it in five minute :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a valid JSON string ([JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) is your friend). You used a comma instead of a colon:

```
{"1":"Active","0","Inactive"} // invalid
{"1":"Active","0":"Inactive"} // valid
```